# Limitar en input para que no se pueda poner "a mano" un valor mayor al stock actual

Tags: html, angular

Estoy empezando con angular y estoy haciendo mi propia página web de prueba. Me surgió una duda de cómo poder "Limitar" en mi input para que no se pueda poner "a mano" un valor mayor a el stock con que cuento... No sé ni como arrancar a hacerlo...

Mi template:

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Imagen</th>
            <th>Nombre</th>
            <th>Marca</th>
            <th>Precio</th>
            <th>Stock</th>
            <th>Compra</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let gamer of gamers" [ngClass]="{'Oferta':gamer.Oferta}">
            <td><img [src]="gamer.Image" [alt]="gamer.Nombre" width="100" height="100"></td>
            <td>{{gamer.Nombre  | uppercase}}</td>
            <td>{{gamer.Marca}}</td>
            <td>{{gamer.Precio  | currency }}</td>
            <td>{{gamer.Stock}}</td>
            <td>
                <button class="btn btn-success" (click)="MenosCantidad(gamer)">-</button>
                <input size=40 style="width:30px" type="text" [(ngModel)]="gamer.Cantidad">
                <button class="btn btn-success"(click)="MasCantidad(gamer)">+</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
       
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Mi arreglo de objetos:

```
export class GamersTandilComponent implements OnInit {

gamers: Gamers [] =  [{  
"Nombre": "Teclado Mecanico",
"Marca": "Logitech",
"Precio": 12000,
"Stock": 5,
"Image": "assets/images/auricularlogitech.jpg",
"Oferta": false,
"Cantidad": 0, 

},

{ 
"Nombre": "Mouse Inalambrico",
"Marca": "Razer",
"Precio": 6500,
"Stock": 12,
"Image": "assets/images/mouserazer.jpg",
"Oferta": true,
"Cantidad": 0,

},


];
```

Me habían recomendado que use `$event`, pero la verdad que no se me ocurre cómo seguir.

Comment: Prueba agregando un `max="{{gamer.Stock}}"` en el input a ver si con eso te vale, pero ponlo con un `type="number"` en lugar de `text`.

Comment: No no me sirvio lo que me pusiste, me sigue dejando escribir la cantidad que yo quiera.

Comment: Sí, ya veo, pero eso tambien es porque no parece que lo tengas en un <form>, pues aunque te deje poner lo que quieras, al intentar enviar el formulario te va a decir que el valor máximo es tal.  Míralo en este [enlace](https://jsfiddle.net/y2os5j6g/)

Comment: Genial, una buena idea entonces seria poner un condicional que si me paso de mi gamer.stock salga un cartel que no cuenta con la cantidad de stock demandada...

Answer (score 0):

Puedes crear un método y llamarlo en el evento keyup del input, puedes agregar también un mensaje indicándole al usuario  de esta manera:

```
  <input size=40 style="width:30px" type="text" [(ngModel)]="gamer.Cantidad" (keyup)="validateStock(gamer.Cantidad, gamer.Stock)">
  <mat-error *ngIf="isNotValid">{{validationMessage}}</mat-error>

  isNotValid: boolean;
  validationMessage: string;

  validateStock(cantidad: number, stock: number) {
    this.isNotValid = false;
    this.validationMessage = '';

    if (cantidad > stock) {
      this.isNotValid = true;
      this.validationMessage = 'La cantidad no puede ser mayor a la existencia.'
      this.gamer.Cantidad = 0;
    }
  }
```